# Is it possible to store Chef cookbook_file source in an encrypted data bag?

Tags: chef-infra

I am using encrypted data bag in Chef and the secret file is currently existing in the source code.

```rb
secret = cookbook_file "/etc/chef/#{env_encrypted_data_bag_secret" do
    source "env_encrypted_data_bag_secret"
    mode 0755
    owner "root"
    group "root"
end
secret.run_action(:create)
```

In the above code, the secret file is loaded from the `files/default` location of the chef repo.

However, it is a security issue to put the secret file in the source code.
So, please let me know if it is possible to store Chef `cookbook_file` source in an encrypted data bag or somewhere else rather than in the chef repo.

Comment: You want to store the secret for your encrypted data bag that contains your secret in an encrypted data bag in a secret data bag secret what? I know the workflow that the encrypted data bag secret is not checked into version control (for good reason), but copied manually between workstations and provisioned to the nodes during boostrapping (`knife bootstrap` copies the file IIRC automatically).

Comment: See [the default bootstrap template](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/a1e923cae62ea09c41bec46adc0b81a46d1ce27e/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb#L198-L203).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Store the data bag secret (file) in your company's password store (or manually pass it between you and your colleagues.
- Specify `knife[:secret_file]` in the [knife config](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife_optional_settings.html) of your workstations to point to that secret file.
- Use `knife bootstrap`, which [automatically copies the secret file](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/a1e923cae62ea09c41bec46adc0b81a46d1ce27e/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb#L198-L203) to the bootstrapped node.

Using this workflow, you won't have to check in the secret into VCS.

Alternatives include [chef-vault](https://github.com/chef/chef-vault), which uses Chef Server's PKI.

Comment: I tried to bootstrap the node but it is not copying the secret file. please let me know what might be missing

Comment: Are you specifying a custom bootstrap template? Do you have `knife[:secret_file]`correctly specified?

Comment: I have `knife[:secret_file]` correctly specified. I am currently using a `validatorlessBootstrap.sh` script designed by someone else in my team. But, can you suggest what bootstrap template/command should i use to copy the secret file?

Comment: The referenced [chef-full.rb](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/a1e923cae62ea09c41bec46adc0b81a46d1ce27e/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates/chef-full.erb) template is the one that chef is using by default already.

Comment: You just must not specify a custom bootstrap template. To make sure, you could add a `--secret-file <path_to_secret_file>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116641/discussion-between-meallhour-and-stephenking).

Answer (score 1):

Stephen gave the more correct answer and you should go accept his, but to further clarify the "why":

If you put the data bag secret somewhere inside Chef's ecosystem (cookbook, Chef Server, whatever) it nullifies the already-ridiculously-minimal security you are getting. The idea of encrypted data bags is to require an out-of-band key exchange before Chef does its thing. As long as that out-of-band exchange is secure and trusted, Chef can leverage that to extend the trust chain to include the encrypted bag items. If you put both halves (the key and the encrypted blob) in the same place or accessible via the same means, you short-circuit the whole idea.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.. I have been trying to transfer an encryption key before my data bag recipe runs and it kept failing. Now I realize it is probably a good thing it doesn't work.